# Solr 500 Error with solr-php-client, CakePHP and Tomcat

Tags: solr, cakephp-1.3, tomcat6

I'm trying to port a CakePHP application from WAMP (development machine) to LAMP (production server). In the WAMP instance submitting a search works. In the LAMP environment, search returns HTTP 500 error. Tomcat6 works and so does the :8080/solr/admin page. The CakePHP webapp works other than search.

Production Environment:
- Ubuntu 10.04
- Apache 2.2.14
- Tomcat6
- Solr 3.4.0
- CakePHP 1.3 (with solr-php-client)
- MySql 5.1.41

Observation: for the same search, the query strings are slightly different between the two environments. The LAMP version seems to be truncated, but I don't know how the value is derived so I can't be sure if the difference is significant.

LAMP (500 error): fields=9546e7be6d1d17fbd2e82f0d49a296b91853ddf0%253A

WAMP (results)  : fields=9546e7be6d1d17fbd2e82f0d49a296b91853ddf0%253An%253A0%253A%257B%257D

Are there logs that might help troubleshoot the 500 error? Are there tests I can run directly through solr/admin that might shed light on the issue?

Comment: Please include the entire generated URLs (that the PHP app generates) and what Solr says when you input the offending URL (enter it into a browser). Also, you affirm that the Solr server remains the same?

Comment: DOESN'T WORK in LAMP
http://example.com/items/search?key=aa1cb20849573226b806d3ab3c83692d64b0c62f&terms=beethoven&Group=&fields=9546e7be6d1d17fbd2e82f0d49a296b91853ddf0%253A


WORKS in WAMP
http://example.com/items/search?key=a51f678792636f7a77e6add069ad02d302b0e74b&terms=beethoven&Group=&fields=9546e7be6d1d17fbd2e82f0d49a296b91853ddf0%253An%253A0%253A%257B%257D

Comment: Solr versions are different. WAMP using 3.3. LAMP using 3.4

Comment: Are you sure they are **Solr** URLs? Enable Tomcat's access logs and get the URLs that cause it to 500. Also see whether the **installation itself** works: try to upload a few documents or check "/select?q=*" from your browser. If they give the same problem, the Solr installation may have broken configuration.

Comment: Finally dawned on me to check Apache log and I see this is an application error. The request is not made to Solr. Apache log shows: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Apache_Solr_Service' not found in /home/eric/cakephp/cakeroot/app/controllers/items_controller.php on line 340, referrer: http://example.com/items/search. So after banging my head against the wall, this is not a Solr/Tomcat issue afterall; it's a Cake issue. Question is now: why does this error occur in LAMP but not WAMP? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. @aitchnyu: Thank you for your time and suggestions.

This turned out to be a CakePHP issue. The code to reference the php-solr-client classes works differently in WAMP and LAMP. In WAMP, code works when capitalizing file/folders properly. In LAMP, the reference must use all lower case with an added parameter containing properly capitalized file/folder names.

Here's where I found the answer:
http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/03/26/loading-vendor-files/

The different URLs in LAMP/WAMP appear to be insignificant.